# Skunk Redux Probability Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, numerical-linear-algebra

Another version of Skunk redux uses a spinner with three equally likely outcomes: 0, 1 and 2, so that 0, 1 and 2 all come up with probability 1/3.  If you are standing when a 1 or 2 comes up you add that to your current score, but if a 0 comes up the game is over and your score is 0.  If you leave the game before a 0 is thrown, your payoff is your score at that point.
(a)  Find the optimal strategy.
(b) Calculate the average payoff obtained using the strategy in (a).  [The game is simple enough that you can simply make a list of all possible trajectories and take the weighted average of their payoffs.  It's useful to lump together (without listing) all trajectories which give you a zero payoff.]
(c)  Calculate the average payoff for the strategy "sit after k spins if the game is not already over" for the values k= 2, 3 and 4, and compare with the answer to (b). You might do k= 2, 3 by making a list of all possible trajectories, but for k = 4 it’s worth trying to find a more general argument, particular anticipating part (d) below.
(d) Calculate the average payoff for the strategy "sit after k spins if the game is not already over" for the general value k

Comment: I upvoted because it is an intelligent question, nicely presented, with (at least) a suggestion that you have done work on this.  Permit me to offer some suggestions:  (1) you are asking mathSE reviewers to do a lot of work to attack **several** questions; some reviewers may be bothered that you have grouped multiple questions into the same query.  If you end up not getting the responses you want, you might consider a "1 at a time approach," breaking this query into several smaller queries, and presenting the queries in a reasonable order, spaced out over several days. ...see next comment

Comment: (2) While I strongly *suspect* that you have already done significant work on these questions, it would help if, however you present the topic, you **always show your work** in the query.

Comment: since this is tagged linear-algebra and probability, you may want to consider using this simple matrix from renewal theory for (b), (c) and (d) $P = 
\left[\begin{matrix} \frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{3}\\
1 & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right]$  with the payoff given by $\mathbf e_1^T P^k\mathbf x$ where $\mathbf x_k$ has consecutive integers (e.g. for k = 1 you'd have $\mathbf x_1 = (1,2)$ and e.g. $\mathbf x_5 = \mathbf x_1 + 4\cdot \mathbf 1$